# How to make post works in select element in HTML

Tags: html, select

```
<form>
    <select name="filter">       
      <option value="1">A</option>
      <option value="2">B</option>                            
    </select>
</form>
```

I want to make this drag down menu post when user selected an item. How to do that?

Alright, try to minimize the JS.

It's something similar to postback in ASP.NET.

Comment: Let see if I understood. You want to send a Post request when the user changes the selected value of the select? Without using JavaScript?

Comment: Not possible without JS. WHy not JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postback in ASP.NET uses JavaScript, it just hides it from you.  If you do not want to use javascript, I do not believe you can accomplish what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible without at least a little bit of JavaScript.

You could do something like this:

```
<form name="myform">
  <select name="filter" onchange="document.myform.submit();">       
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>                            
  </select>
</form>
```